# jQuery object properties instead of classes

Tags: jquery, html, css, events, jquery-animate

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
  var link = $(this);

  if (!link.hasClass('animated')) {
    link.addClass('animated');

    // css3 animation

    // callback
    setTimeout(function() {
      link.removeClass('animated');
    }, 600);
    }
  }
});
```

I use this code for preventing animation flickering. It checks for the animated class existance before making some animations. I don't use `animate` function because of its poor performance.

So I understand, that each time I'm asking to do something with classes, I'm affecting the DOM.

I wonder if can I use additional properties on the `link` object instead of using classes? Like:

```
link.animated = true;

if (link.animated) {
  // code
}

link.active = true;
```

Is it safe to use them in following way? Any issues I can face with (caching or whatelse)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method to store associated data with an element:

```
var $link = $(this);

//set
$link.data({ foo: 1 });

//get
var foo = $link.data('foo');
```

Comment: `data` function affects DOM

Comment: @Steve No, it's saved in jQery's `$.cache`. The element is only a reference (key) to the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.data()` instead of class

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var link = $(this);

    if (!link.data('animation')) {
        link.data('animation', true);

        // css3 animation

        // callback
        setTimeout(function() {
            link.data('animation', false);
        }, 600);
    }

});
```

Comment: I think that the `data` function also affects DOM

Comment: @Steve no jQuery uses an internal data structure to store data, it does not store it in the dom

Comment: but if I check this (not $(this)) for $.data, it will give a right result. Also the same result for the checking outside the function, or anywhere I will call for $.data. So it look like jQuery always adds the data attribute on `.data()`.

Comment: What do you think about storing properties directly inside the $(this) object? like `link = $(this); link.someproperty = 'value'`?

Comment: data isn't a right choice, since classes have a better performance http://jsperf.com/state-from-class-or-data-attr